# WPF Affect all types of an element (Stackpanel) programatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to hide all Stackpanels when a button is clicked programatically, how can I accomplish this?

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Click="toggle_stackpanels" />

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="505" Margin="705,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" Background="#FFD82727"/>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="505" Margin="655,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Background="#FF6DEA49"/>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="505" Margin="600,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" Background="#FF1F92BD"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public void toggle_stackpanels(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Hide All Stackpanels
}
```

Comment: Multiple options: 1) Enumerate `Grid.Children` and hide each control which `is StackPanel` 2) Bind each `StackPanel.Visibility` to something what will be changed in `toggle_stackpanels` 3) Use `ToggleButton` and bind panels visibility to its `IsChecked` (using `BoolToVisibility` converter). Consider to put `StackPanels` into single container which you then hide.

Comment: Please tell us what you do not get to do.